# The this keyword in the context below android programming

Tags: android, android-activity, android-context

Hi am trying to figure out how the code below works and its meaning:

```
    public Context mContext;
    private Common mApp;
    public Activity mActivity;

    mContext = this;
    mActivity = this;
    mApp = (Common) mContext.getApplicationContext()
```

for me to invoke a method i need to create an object of that class as follows

```
  Context mContext = new Context();

and then i would be able to invoke the method getAppliationContext as shown above:

 mContext.getApplicationContext()
```

can someone explain that for me please,and also how is the this keyword applying above.From what i know is the this keyword is a reference to the object itself.
Also i don't understand how "mApp" is being used as an object to invoke the various methods below:

```
     int startCount = mApp.getSharedPreferences().getInt("START_COUNT", 1);
    mApp.getSharedPreferences().edit().putInt("START_COUNT", startCount+1).commit();
```

yet it has not been created by using the new keyword,i would think that i would need to do the following inorder to invoke a method using mApp:

Common mApp = new Common();

so that i would be able to do this

```
    int startCount = mApp.getSharedPreferences().getInt("START_COUNT", 1);
    mApp.getSharedPreferences().edit().putInt("START_COUNT", startCount+1).commit();
```

I think where i am heading at is,are there other ways to create an object without using the new keyword only.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the context by invoking `getApplicationContext()` on any class that is extending context object. 
As the name suggests, its the context of current state of the application/object.

eg: `Activity`, `IntentService`, `BroadcastReceiver` etc.

```
Context context=getApplicationContext();
```

After obtaining context object, you can call context class methods inside any class.

eg:

```
 context.startActivity();
 context.getSharedPrefereces();
 context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);      
 context.getContentResolver().query(uri, ...);
```

Comment: Thanks ,does this mean that the getApplicationContext() method returns an object of type Context ? and we assign this object to the refernce context ?

Comment: @kobewarui yes, it returns an object of type Context

Answer (score 0):

You're exactly right about this `this` keyword.

The `Activity` class extends the `Context` class. The `this` keyword can therefore be used in the `Activity` class to reference both an Activity object and a `Context` object as an object of type `Activity` is simply an extended version of `Context` and therefore has all of its methods and variables inherited. See here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

I have never seen `Common` within the Android API but it's casted from a `Context` object, therefore I will treat it as if it is a `Context` object. The reason you don't have to instantiate the `Context` object to call its methods is because you've already assigned a `Context` instance to `mApp` in this example.

Comment: Thanks for the insight,does this mean that the refernce mContext and mActivity is assigned to an object by using the this keyword:           mContext = this;
                   mActivity = this;

Comment: Exactly. `mContext` and `mActivity` would be assigned the object instance of the class they're written in.

Comment: And by doing that we can invoke methods of that class or the class that has been extended by using those references ? We dont have to use the new keyword ?

Comment: Yes, you can and no, you don't have to use new, seeing as the new keyword would only produce a new object instance of that class inside the class object. In this example, you're referencing the already created object instance.